# How can I build graphql lambda with API Gateway websocket?

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-api-gateway

I am building a graphql in nodejs, using [michalkvasnicak/aws-lambda-graphql](https://github.com/michalkvasnicak/aws-lambda-graphql) to work with lambda. And use API Gateway as the endpoint for my lambda. It works fine for HTTP connection. But how can I make it work with websocket connection?

I see in the API Gateway, I need to define `$connect`, `$default` and routes but I don't know how I can make them work with my graphql lambda?

Comment: First question when reading the readme.md, have you wired/configured `subscriptions-transport-ws` properly? `export const handleWebSocket = server.createWebSocketHandler();`

Comment: yes I have added that. But I don't know how the routes in API gateway maps to my graphql lambda